# Matlab: save confusion matrix to file

Tags: matlab

I would like to save on file the confusion matrix that I get after the training phase.

```
[m,order]=confusionmat(YPred,YValidation)
m =
    18     8     3 
     3     5     1
     3     7    20
order = 
  7×1 categorical array
     classA
     classB
     classC
```

How can I save the confusion matrix with the labels associated with the columns and rows in a csv file?

Expected result

```
;ClassA;ClassB;ClassC
classA;18;8;0
classB;3;5;1     
classC;3;7;20
```

Comment: Does your MATLAB have the [`writecell()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writecell.html) function?

Comment: yes, the function is present @Vicky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assemble a cell array with your data and then export it:

```
q=cellstr(order);
writecell( [ {[]} q.'; q num2cell( m ) ], 'foo.txt', 'Delimiter', ';' );
```